# How can I find ParentDirectory

Tags: java, java-ee-7

I am sorry,may be this is simple question.

I am finding real Path from my web-content folder in the following way.

```
String directory= request.getRealPath("/JSPFiles");
```

I got output like this.

```
 C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore\DesktopSubbuFinal\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ExecutableFileProcess\JSPFiles
```

I want to find Parent Directory from `directory` varibale.

```
C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore\DesktopSubbuFinal\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ExecutableFileProcess
```

Thanks.

Comment: @I am new to `Java`.I searched in google but I didn't get it.

Comment: use lastIndexOf function.

Comment: @user2642355. Look into the `File` class API. You would get what you want.

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks for you suggestion.I posted answer what I tried.It's working fine.Check it once and tell me is there any simple way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did in the following way

```
   String n=request.getRealPath("/JSPFiles");
   File j=new File(n);
   String jk=j.getParent();
   out.print(jk);
```

Comment: Yeah you found the correct way. Look how you can find the answer yourself, going through the API. Now you can accept your answer.

Comment: @RohitJain I seen Java Api,it's very difficult to find because it have so many packages. So I need push up.Anyhow Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

*Alternative way by splitting strings*

To get `ExecutableFileProcess` from that string, or any parent directory for that matter, you can use the `split` function from the `String` class, and index the array:

```
String parentDirectory = directory.split("\\\\")[directory.split("\\\\").length-1];
```